# How can I search only the posts that I voted on?

Tags: support, voting, search

I want to search text in only those questions for which I have voted.

Here is a screen shot of the questions I have voted on.  I need to search text there.
[image]

Comment: does it mean that if any person has high rep he knows everything. If u can help that would be appreciated.

Comment: If you find my previous comment rude, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to. No, I don't mean a high-rep user should know everything. The thing is, when a newbie asks a question with not good enough quality, we usually leave a comment like "Welcome to Stack Overflow, you should read the help center and improve your question by blah, blah" and expect the newbie to improve his question. It doesn't make sense to tell you that. Back to your question, how hard is it to use the correct spelling? It's really not about knowing everything, it's about showing respect to people who reads and answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. To be very honestly i do not know can i search text for those question where i gave my vote.please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: This is currently not possible. There is already a [pending feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89555/search-among-posts-youve-voted-for) on MSE, nothing more we can do.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to perform such a search given the options available to us.