# Can I see when I voted on a question?

Tags: support, voting, history

Re. Duplicate: that question is asking *how to see* old votes. My question is about *searching* old votes to *see when they were cast*. My question is much more specific than the proposed duplicate, and has received an appropriate answer. Please re-open this question

---

I came to SO looking for info on VS [Build Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties), and scrolled down and found exactly what I was looking for. I decided to go up-vote the question, and saw I already had!

Is there a way to see exactly when (even just to the day) when I up-voted the question?

I know I can see a list of my votes, but having no idea when I voted on this particular question, I'm really not fond of the idea of having to search through all of my history by hand. Further, I'm not looking to be able to search all my votes, just my vote on this one question.

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327372/an-ablity-to-see-when-i-have-voted) on meta, but that would involve (if the question has been edited since) possibly un-voting and re-voting, which would reset the original time I voted, which would invalidate the very information I'm looking for. If my vote has truly been locked in, the tool-tip saying I can't un-vote has the info. So why can't I see that?

Re. Duplicate: that question is asking how to see old votes. My question is about searching old votes to see when they were cast. My question is much more specific than the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Just for the record, my vote was over 2 years ago, had I tried to un-vote, it's been edited since, and I would have lost this info

Comment: I had originally interpreted this question as more of "show in the tooltip when I voted on a post", or something to that effect.  Much like hovering over various features on the page show the precise time of the action.  Is this question about searching for the vote or about displaying better contextual information about it?  The clarification of the duplicate seems to contradict the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can see when you upvoted a question [by navigating to your voting history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007939/cdspace?tab=votes&sort=upvote) (and specifically selecting "upvotes") in your profile.

However, there is no way to actively *search* on specific questions that were voted on.

Comment: I addressed this in my question. I don't want to have to search all of that by hand, since [I can't automatically search it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275582/how-can-i-search-only-the-posts-that-i-voted-on)

Comment: @CDspace:  There's no real way to accomplish that, then.  The only thing you can do is look at the listing and search through that.  Searching through your vote history implies that the vote history is indexed, and that would likely go against the privacy policy put in place for keeping your votes anonymous.  I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Does hovering over the upvote button show a tooltip of when you voted? Can't remember if it does or not or if I'm confusing that with something else.

Comment: @JonClements:  You're confusing that with something else.  The tooltips for votes only indicate why you're voting.

Comment: Just try to remove your vote. If it's past the grace period, it won't let you and instead you'll see a pop-up indicating when you cast that vote.

Comment: @CodyGray That's addressed in the question, with the linked meta-question. If the post has been edited, then trying to undo my vote will work, and clear the info I'm looking for

Comment: @Makoto Oh... Was thinking of the case the OP linked in their question - so only half-confused :)

Comment: @CodyGray If my vote is locked in, the pop-up can tell me when I voted... so maybe I should edit this into a feature request to add that info to the vote button tool-tips, once you've voted

Comment: @CDspace I guess it depends whether it knows it's locked in before trying the undo attempt which returns the message with the datetime in. On mobile at moment but does that element have any data attributes with a datetime for it in the page source itself?

Comment: @JonClements Not that I can see regarding the voting buttons or question score

Comment: Never mind about the feature request, [already asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349624/why-cant-we-see-when-we-last-voted-a-question-by-hovering-the-vote-arrows?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something critical about the Votes table in [the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), but [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/716204#resultSets) shows all of your votes, which does not include a vote for that particular post.

Comment: @Joe:  That *only* shows their favorites. A `VoteTypeId` of 5 [maps to Favorite](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types), which *is* publicly visible.

Comment: @Makoto Ahh, okay - that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to feed that page into google with `site:` argument?